# Disable @SqsListener for local environment

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have the following value configured in my SQS Listener in springboot. The queue is configured only for DEV and STAGE environments. So I want to disable it in my local after testing. How do i achieve that?

```
@SqsListener(value = { "${cloud.aws.endpoint}" } , deletionPolicy =SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void processMessage(String message) throws Exception {
}
```

I tried to add the following to my application-local.xml(to keep it local), but it didn't work. Anyone went through the same scenario?

```
autoconfigure:
  exclude:
    - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.messaging.MessagingAutoConfiguration
    - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration
    - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration
```

I am getting the following error everytime.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoDetectingStackNameProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackNameProvider]: Factory method 'autoDetectingStackNameProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid instance id defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.867.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Host is down (connect failed)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoDetectingStackNameProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackNameProvider]: Factory method 'autoDetectingStackNameProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No valid instance id defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.sprin
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issues while using `@SqsListener`. What I usually do is comment out the annotation when running the app locally - it's ugly but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Profile("!local")
```

- put on you listener class if it's `@Component`,
- or to your `@Bean` method

When your active Spring profile will be **local**, then is would skip this Bean.